# find option by value error: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: java, selenium, selector, selenide

I have a simple method that should find selected options in a multiselect and check its' values. Here it is:

```
public void checkArticleCategories(String cat1, String cat2)
{
    ElementsCollection options = $(byName("categories[]")).findAll(":selected");

    options.find(value(cat1)).shouldHave(value(cat1), ofSeconds(14));
    options.find(value(cat2)).shouldHave(value(cat2), ofSeconds(14));
}
```

But `.shouldHave(value(cat1)` throws an error:

> invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

All types are right. Parameter of `shouldHave()` is of `Condition` class as expected and `value()` expects string. So what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not on the line with options.find() but in the :selected selector above. And as author of Selenide framework wrote it is necessary to allow this type of selectors manualy:

```
Configuration.selectorMode = SelectorMode.Sizzle;
```